# Create a reusable dialog in Angular

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material

I want to create a reusable dialog in Angular.
For example, a dialog might consist of just a title, a message, and a yes/no button.
Another dialog could also have a dropdown.
The function called when you click Yes or No is different for each dialog.

How can I implement this?

This is what my current code looks like. So far I've only managed to make my title, message and button texts dynamic.

dialog.component.html

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>{{data?.title}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  {{data?.message}}
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-raised-button mat-dialog-close>{{data?.confirmText}}</button>
  <button mat-raised-button mat-dialog-close cdkFocusInitial>{{data?.cancelText}}</button>
</div>
```

dialog.component.ts

```
import { DialogData } from './../../models/dialog-data';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.scss'],
})
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

dialog.service.ts

```
export class DialogService {

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

  openDialog(data: DialogData): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
      data,
      width: '400px',
      disableClose: true
    }).afterClosed();
  }
}
```

dialog-data.ts

```
export interface DialogData {
  title: string;
  message: string;
  confirmText: string;
  cancelText: string;
}
```

openDialog()

```
openDialog() {
    this.dialogService.openDialog({
      title: 'Title',
      message: 'message',
      confirmText: 'Yes',
      cancelText: 'No',
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the code for "OK" and "Cancel" functions in two ways:

1. If you are closing the dialog on click of "OK" and "Cancel" then write the code in afterclosed:

   const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
   data: {
   title: 'Title',
   message: 'message',
   confirmText: 'Yes',
   cancelText: 'No',
   });

   dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(confirm => {
   if (confirm) {
   // do something on "OK" click
   } else{
   // do something on "OK" click
   } });
2. If you are not closing the dialog on "OK" and "Cancel" click:

You have to pass data while calling the dialog with an injectable data:

```
 const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, { 
data: { 
title: 'Title',
 message: 'message',
 confirmText: 'Yes',
 cancelText: 'No', 
isDataFromHome:true //pass a variable from another components as well and check the value of this variable in dialog component, on the basis of which you can define different functions on OK and Cancel
});
```

Comment: This way you can't actually make the dialog do anything before it just closes. I think we need a solution that enables us to run the a submit function, once its done successfully only then we close the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need absolute flexibility then it makes sense to create two different dialog components and trigger corresponding dialog depending on input parameters, similarly you can use `ngSwitch`/`ngIf` in the dialog component to show input depending on the provided parameters. If you still want flexibility then you can pass `TemplateRef` in the dialog parameters and render input component dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage **Content Projection** for specifying the dynamic content of the dialog parts.

Dialog.html:

```
<div class="dialog-content">
    <mat-dialog-content>
        <div class="header">
            <h1 class="title">{{title}}</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <ng-content select=".content">
            </ng-content>
        </div>
    </mat-dialog-content>

    <mat-dialog-actions>
        <div class="dialog-buttons">
            <ng-content select=".buttons">
            </ng-content>
        </div>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
</div>
```

Ok dialog (just title and ok button):

```
<my-dialog [title]="title">
    <div class="buttons">
        <button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="onOk()">
            {{ okText }}
        </button>
    </div>
</my-dialog>
```